# Excel - hide the same columns across multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I need to hide the same columns across several workbooks.

For example, I want to hide columns `B, C, F, H, I, J, K, R, Q, AA`, etc, and I need to hide those same columns in many different workbooks quickly upon opening these workbooks. In other words,

I need to create a custom view that I can apply to any workbook I open, quickly.

I am using Excel 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: For that, you can record a macro and adapt it according to your needs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For this, you'll need a macro in VBA. You can create a Loop that checks the workbooks you select, opens each workbook, hides columns in the sheet you want, and then close the workbook. But the only way to achieve this, as far as I know, is a macro with VBA.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I ended up recording a macro, it works very well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a workbook open event to set the properties of the columns you want:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Range("B:D,F:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ... and this hides those columns for all worksheets? Or just for the active one?

Comment: @dominique Since the OP didn't mention anything about hiding columns in other sheets, I didn't include it. For all we know, he only has one worksheet per workbook. Rawrplus's example illustrates that really well, but not on opening the workbook, which was my interpretation of what John wanted.

Comment: This is a flexible solution. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `For Each` loop to loop through the collection of `Workbooks` and `Worksheets` respectively and repeat an action *"`for each`"* and every one of them.

```
Private Sub hide_columns()

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each wb In Workbooks ' loop through all workbooks
     For Each ws In wb.Worksheets ' loop through all worksheets in workbooks
        ws.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ws.Columns("H:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ' - add the rest of the columns here 
     Next ws
   Next wb

End Sub
```